# Setting own proxy during @PostConstruct phase causes @Transactional problems

Tags: java, spring, validation, proxy, transactions

I have my service which does some @Transactional work. If I mark it @Validated I will receive org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at point (B). If I remove line (A) everything works as expected. My service is validated and works in transaction again. It doesn't matter if I use this proxy object later or not. Once it is initialized in the @PostConstruct phase it can not be @Transactional. The same if I try to use InitializingBean interface. Could anyone explain me why? Shouldn't @PostConstruct method be invoked after all the proxies are created?

I have done a simple workaround for that by using getter instead of instance variable. So I can ask application context when my bean is fully initialized and then everything works fine.

```
@Service
@Lazy(value = true)
//@Validated
public class XXXXServiceImpl implements XXXService {

  private String name;

  private XXXService proxy;

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Override
  public void setBeanName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct() {
    proxy = (XXXService)applicationContext.getBean(name); // (A)
  }

  @Transactional
  public void test(Company object) {
       License l = licenseDAO.find(1234);
       l.getCompany(); // (B)
  }
}
```

workaround

```
private XXXService getProxy() {
  if (proxy == null)
    proxy = (XXXService)applicationContext.getBean(name);
  return proxy;
}
```

stacktrace: (from my real code, not simplified)

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at pl.xxx.bean.CompanyIdentity_$$_jvstd73_f.getId(CompanyIdentity_$$_jvstd73_f.java)
    at pl.xxx.services.AdminServiceImpl.cleanTestData_aroundBody12(AdminServiceImpl.java:228)
    at pl.xxx.services.AdminServiceImpl$AjcClosure13.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at pl.xxx.services.AdminServiceImpl.cleanTestData(AdminServiceImpl.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor$HibernateValidatorDelegate.invokeWithinValidation(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
```

Comment: I'm confused. What are you marking `@Validated`? Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: I doesn't matter what. Adding this annotation makes this bug. Probably anyway springs creates a proxy. It does not have to have any method validated.

Comment: I have added the stacktrace